# How to change position in the toggler menu

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to change position in my toggler navbar.
In the md and bigger i have this: NAME - Picture - Button,
but in toggler menu i want to show in reverse - Picture-name-button.
How can i do this?

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex ">

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <span>Mark Hohmann</span>
          <img src="https://evdo8pe.cloudimg.io/s/resizeinbox/400x400/http://b2bnew.widmannsrl.com/ImmaginiSitoB2B/Articoli/max/C6366_nc__C6366_a.jpg" alt="foto" class="rounded-circle ml-1" height="50" width="50">
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </li>           
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please include the complete Navbar code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the  element order like below:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav d-flex ">

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

      <img src="https://evdo8pe.cloudimg.io/s/resizeinbox/400x400/http://b2bnew.widmannsrl.com/ImmaginiSitoB2B/Articoli/max/C6366_nc__C6366_a.jpg" alt="foto" class="rounded-circle ml-1" height="50" width="50">
       <span>Mark Hohmann</span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
    </div>
</li>           
</ul>
```